# How do I set this shadow effect in an image around a div element?

Tags: css

Here's an image of what I want:

[image]

I want to have a similar light gray shadow effect around an element;
I tried setting CSS properties related to the border, but it didn't work out.

My idea is to use the gradient effect of css, but I am not particularly familiar with the gradient of css.

Comment: "*I tried setting CSS properties...[It] didn't work out.*" - what CSS did you write? What went wrong? What HTML are you working with to create this layout? Please, read the guidelines - "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" - and take the [tour] of the site to see how it works, and what our expectations are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) CSS property:

```css
/* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 1rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
```

```css
body { padding: 1em; }

.my-btn {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 1rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  font-size: 2em;
}

.my-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 1rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.my-btn:active {
  background: #222;
  color: #EEE;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 1rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<button class="my-btn">待评价</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Css:

```
.btn {
width:200px;
height:150px;
border:none;
outline:none;
box-shadow:2px 2px 12px 2px #efefef;
border-radius:8px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="btn">Hello</div>
```